# Is CMake part of Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, cmake

Is CMake part of Android Studio? When I tried to do a Gradle Sync in Android Studio, I got an error that the CMake is too early a version and I need to update it. But I get this error even if I uninstall CMake. This tells me that CMake must be embedded somehow in Android Studio. So, how can I fix this? Please help.

This happens even if I remove cmake from the command line. So it seems that cmake is embedded into Android Studio. So how do I update cmake if it is part of Android Studio somehow?

When running the Gradle Sync command in Android Studio I get an error message that the CMake is outdated and I need to download a later version.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Its used to compile C code for native C/C++ libraries if you have any, I believe.

Answer (score 0):

You have a number of options when it comes to Android Studio and CMake:

1. Use the one that comes from the SDK manager. You can get it installed by gradle at sync time by specifying a version as described [here.](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/install-ndk#vanilla_cmake). Beware though, there are limited versions available from there. To see what's available (or install it manually pre-sync) open the manager (the cube with the blue downwards arrow from the toolbar you have in your screenshot), select the "SDK tools" tab, and then tick "Show package details" from the bottom right and scroll through to the CMake section of the tree.
2. Use one you've installed from CMake's install channels or built yourself. Make sure the executable is available on the PATH variable, and make sure its version is listed in your `build.gradle` as described in the link above.